# In memory, .NET Core HTTP Server for one request

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to setup some integration tests for my OAuth2 and OIDC systems.  For that to work I need to have a callback URL.  For that I need to have an HTTP server running in memory long enough to catch the redirect.  (I am following this [example](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/16/oauth-2-command-line) that is written in PHP.)

I have not seen anything about how to host a simple, in memory, HTTP server in .NET Core.  (There is a lot of stuff about how to make an HTTP *Call*, but that is not what I need.)

My goal is to make this not require any setup on my host machine.  (I would like to just be able to run the tests from any server and have it work.)

**How can I setup an in memory HTTP Server to receive a single redirect?**

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in LinqPad with the following code:

```
async void Main()
{
    string[] args = new string[] { };

    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)     
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5001");
            webBuilder.Configure(app => app.Run(async ctx => 
            { 
                if (ctx.Request.Path == "/favicon.ico")
                    return;

                await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Request Receivied");             
            }));            
        });
```

I also added the following NuGet:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting

And the following includes:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting

Lastly the `Reference ASP.NET Core assemblies` checkbox in the bottom right of the Query Properties (F4) needs to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Feather HTTP](https://github.com/featherhttp/framework). You can run HTTP server like

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = WebApplication.Create(args);

        app.MapGet("/", async http =>
        {
            await http.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World");
        });

        await app.RunAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this for integration testing, you should use [`WebApplicationFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-3.0) from the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing) NuGet package. Microsoft has a [thorough article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) about this approach, a default example:

```cs
public class BasicTests 
    : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> _factory;

    public BasicTests(WebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("/")]
    [InlineData("/Index")]
    [InlineData("/About")]
    [InlineData("/Privacy")]
    [InlineData("/Contact")]
    public async Task Get_EndpointsReturnSuccessAndCorrectContentType(string url)
    {
        // Arrange
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
        Assert.Equal("text/html; charset=utf-8", 
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    }
}
```